# How To Make a Clone Follow A Turtle

Tags: python, datatable, append, turtle-graphics

I am making a snake game. I have created a clone every time I touch the fruit. It creates a clone but I need that clone to follow the player on the back of the head. Then I need the other clone that gets created when I touch the fruit again to connect to the back of the clone.

This is the code for the turtle.clone()

```
    if player.distance(fruit) < 22:
      fruit.goto(randint(-180,0),randint(0,180))
      score = score + 1
      #Sound
      os.system("afplay Sound.wav&")
      #Writing Score
      turtle.clear()
      turtle.write(f"Score = {score}", font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))
      Body_Parts = Body_Parts + 1
      #Add Turtle
      player.clone()
      
      #Adding To Table
      Parts.append(f"Body{Body_Parts}")
      print(Parts)
```

Under the player.clone() I want to add the code you help me with.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
turtle.clone()
```

clones the turtle, if you want to make it follow you can do something like

```
xc = fruit.xcor()
yc = fruit.ycor()
"make the clone lets say that you made the clone "clone""
while .....:
      clone.setx(xc-10)
      clone.sety(yc-10)
```